# list of value objects not persisting

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this mapping:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Blas)
                  .Component(comp =>
                  {
                      comp.Map(x => x.X1);
                      comp.Map(x => x.X2);
                  }).Cascade.All();
```

Unfortunately, the value object Bla stored in a list called Blas is not persistet. The table for bla value objects exists and the parent object, which holds the list Blas, is nicely persisted. I thought that the Cascade.All takes care of the 'fluent' persistence of Bla objects but this does not seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class Bla has its own table, you have to provide a normal mapping for it. Component maps the properties to the same table, which should not work inside a HasMany statement. So make a `ClassMap<Bla>` and remove the `Component` statement.